# Data from TouchJSON getting deallocated

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I have an NSArray stored as a property of my class with a retain attribute.  I use a NSURLConnection to return me data as JSON.  I use TouchJSON to convert it into a NSDictionary object which I store into the array.  I'm using this array as the datasource for a UITableView, but after scrolling through the table a few times I get a message sent to deallocated object error.

I get the error even if I retain receivedData and searchResults.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

```
@property(retain) NSArray *myArray;
```

(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

```
// Once we get response, parse it
NSError *error;
NSData *receivedData = [connectionInfo objectForKey:@"receivedData"];
NSDictionary *searchResults = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:receivedData error:&error];

self.myArray = [searchResults objectForKey:@"myData"];
```

}

-[CFDictionary objectForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14a0b70

More details: myArray is an array of dictionaries and the error occurs  when I call

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[myDict objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Comment: To my eyes it is a bit odd to retain the copy. If you want to copy the array use that in the @property declaration. Where are you releasing myArray?

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if the copy was necessary, but I have the same issue with or without it.  I'm not releasing myArray anywhere.

Comment: Maybe not releasing it, but it sounds like you're autoreleasing the array somewhere though. If you aren't doing it explicitly directly, then more than likely one of your methods is doing it for you. Please post more code.